# Use grep() to select character strings with "XXX-0000" syntax

Tags: r, regex, string, character

Given a character vector:

```
    id.data = c("XXX-2355",
                "XYz-03",
                "XYU-3", 
                "ABC-1234",
                "AX_2356",
                "AbC234")
```

What is the appropriate way to grep for ONLY the entries that DONT'T follow an "XXX-0000" pattern? In the example above I'd want to end up with only "XXX-2355" and "ABC-1234". There are tens of thousands of records.

I tried selecting by individual issue. For example,

```
    id.error = rep(NA, length(id.data))
    id.error[-grep("-", id.data)] = "hyphen"
```

This was obviously really inefficient and I have no way of knowing every possible error. Strplit was useful to a point, but only when I know where to split.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`invert`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

> `invert`  logical. If `TRUE` return indices or values for elements that do *not* match.

```
> id.data = c("XXX-2355",
+                 "XYz-03",
+                 "XYU-3",
+                 "ABC-1234",
+                 "AX_2356",
+                 "AbC234")
> grep("[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}", id.data)
[1] 1 4
> grep("[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}", id.data, value = TRUE)
[1] "XXX-2355" "ABC-1234"
> grep("[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}", id.data, invert = TRUE)
[1] 2 3 5 6
> grep("[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}", id.data, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
[1] "XYz-03"  "XYU-3"   "AX_2356" "AbC234"
>
```

<sub>Not sure whether you want strings that match the said pattern, or those that don't match.  The above example lists both options.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
library(stringr)
id.data[str_detect(id.data, "[A-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}")]
> [1] "XXX-2355" "ABC-1234"
```

Comment: he wants the ones that don't follow this pattern so `id.data[! str_detect(id.data, "[A-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}")]`